# study of the Picard Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

i try to study a picard theorem but on one part of the proof i see this result and idk how to solve it.

Suppose $J$ is a closed and bounded interval, and let

$Y=\{f \in C[a,b]: f[a,b]\subset J\}$

Show that $Y \subset C[a,b]$  is closed.

My idea $J \subset \mathbb{R}$ and closet then $J$ is complete space, for other hand $[a,b]$ is compact and $f$ is continuos then $f([a,b])$ is compact then is closet but idk how to continue if someone can help me...

Comment: Hint: We have a metric (or norm) on $C[a,b]$. Prove that if $f_1,f_2,...$ is a sequence in $Y$ converging to $f$, then $f\in Y$.

Comment: If i considerer $d_\infty$ In this case is easy to see if $f_1,f_2...$ is a sequence in $Y$ all are continuos and have uniform convergence then f is a continuos function on $[a,b]$ so $f \in C[a,b]$ ??

Comment: What do you mean by $d_\infty$? The metric I was talking about is $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$.

Comment: yes the same metric in my workbook is $d_\infty$

Comment: Okay. Yeah we know the limit $f$ must also be continuous. Now show that $f(x)\in J$ for any $x\in[a,b]$. Then we've shown $f\in Y$.

Comment: Let $\phi_x(f) = f(x)$, show that $\phi_x$ is continuous and $Y = \cap_{x \in [a,b]} \phi_x^{-1} (J)$. You only need $J$ to be closed. Bounded is not necessary.

Comment: Wait i have it if I take $f_1(x_0)$ I know $f_1(x_0) \in J$ next $f_2(x_0) \in J$ ... If I do this I have a sequence such that $(f_n(x_0) )\subset J$ size J is close I have $f(x_0) \in J$